# Expected identifier. - XP VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need help again...

This time, (i narrowed it down to a sub)

```
Sub Copy(from, to)
oCMD.run "%COMSPEC% /c xcopy /y /e " &  from  & " " & to
End Sub
```

gives me

[error2.PNG - click to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3xka2aqkh61i5n/error2.PNG?dl=1)

I'm so confused, and I can't get any other details from Windows Script Host. :(

What's the matter, XP?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`From` and `To` are reserved words. Choose other names.

Update (sorry):

`To` is a reserved word. Choose another name. My apologies to `From`.

Evidence:

```
>> Function f0(f, t) : End Function
>>
>>
>> Function f1(from, t) : End Function
>>
>>
>> Function f2(frm, to) : End Function
>>
Error Number:       1010
Error Description:  Expected identifier
```

Update wrt comment:

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) to learn why `Copy("D:\", User(Scott) & "\Desktop\CD-ROM\")` is wrong. Then remove the parentheses.

Comment: Okay. I'll try, I'll comment again if it does not work.

Comment: It fixes the firs error, but then it comes up with
"Line: 46, Char: 48, Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub"
Line 46 is `Copy("D:\", User(Scott) & "\Desktop\CD-ROM\")`.

Comment: It did not help... :(